# How to create a Meeting booking app in Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, node-modules

I want to build a node js app that can book meetings between a teacher a student using node js, react, MongoDB, and other required things. Can anyone help with how to plan such an app? Can you show us some examples that we can follow to build our app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take inspiration for the application from this [general purpose react planner](https://github.com/VanessaCHW/pink-planner).

Related information from : https://reactjsexample.com/a-react-application-for-managing-events-and-meetings/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.